# Average of values from multiple matrices in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, mean

I have 50 matrices contained in one folder, all of dimension 181 x 360. How do I cycle through that folder and take an average of each corresponding data points across all 50 matrices?

Comment: How are the matrices stored? `.mat` files? `.txt` files?  If they're in `.txt` files, are they stored in row major format? Column major format? Is each row / column carriage return separated? There are too many things you haven't told us.  We're here to answer questions, not try and read your mind.

Comment: They are in .dat format. I can open each individually using fopen/fread(name, 'float'), then use the reshape command to go from 65160x1 to 360x181, before finally inverting the matrix to get to 181x360. I'm not sure if that's necessarily what you need though?

Answer (score 1):

If the matrices are contained within Matlab variables stored using `save('filename','VariableName')` then they can be opened using `load('filename.mat')`.

As such, you can use the result of `filesInDirectory = dir;` to get a list of all your files, using a search pattern if appropriate, like `files = dir('*.mat');`

Next you can use your `load` command, and then `whos` to see which variables were loaded. You should consider storing these for ease clearing after each iteration of your loop.

Once you have your matrix loaded (one at a time), you can take averages as you need, probably summing a value across multiple loop iterations, then dividing by a total counter you've been measuring (using perhaps `count = count + size(MatrixVar, dimension);`).

If you need all of the matrices loaded at once, then you can modify the above idea, to `load` using a loop, then average outside of the loop. In this case, you may need to take care - but 50*181*360 isn't too bad I suspect.

A brief introduction to the `load` command can be found at [this](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~gerry/MATLAB/plotting/loadingPlotData.html) link. It talks mainly about opening one matrix, then plotting the values, but there are some comments about dealing with headers, if needed, and different ways in which you can open data, if `load` is insufficient. It doesn't talk about binary files, though.

**Note on binary files, based on comment to OP's question**:

If the file can be opened using

```
FID = fopen('filename.dat');
fread(FID, 'float');
```

then you can replace the steps referring to `load` above, and instead use a loop to find filenames using `dir`, open the matrices using `fopen` and `fread`, then average as needed, finally closing the files and `clear`ing the matrices.

In this case, probably your file identifier is the only part you're likely to need to change during the loop (although your total will increase, if that's how you want to average your data)

Reshaping the matrix, or inverting it, might make the code clearer (which is good!), but might not be necessary depending on what you're trying to average - it may be that selecting only a subsection of the matrix is sufficient.

**Possible example code?**

Assuming that all of the files in the current directory are to be opened, and that no files are elsewhere, you could try something like:

```
listOfFiles = dir('*.dat');
for f = 1:size(listOfFiles,1)
    FID = fopen(listOfFiles(f).name);
    Data = fread(FID, 'float');
    % Reshape if needed?
    Total = Total + sum(Data(start:end,:)); % This might vary, depending on what you want to average etc.
    Counter = Counter + (size(Data,1) * size(Data,2)); % This product will be the 181*360 you had in the matrix, in this case
end

Av = Total/Counter;
```

Comment: The matrices themselves are contained each within one .dat file, so I'm not sure that's the same as being contained within matlab variables, is it? Sorry I'm just kinda learning matlab at the moment.

Comment: If the file is ASCII (and you can, for example, open it with a text editor and see real values in nice columns etc), then the `load` command should still work, although not using a '.mat' extension in that case, obviously. I think that when you open an ASCII file in that way, the variable into which the data is saved has the same name as the file, minus the (.dat) extension

Comment: If you have a binary file, then you'll have more difficulty - if so, let me know, but then you're going to need a lot more information about it's formatting etc - in that case, your data probably has a header/info file somewhere?

Comment: The data is in a binary format, I'm gonna have to find the header/info though.

Comment: Looks like you have enough, from your comment to the question - if you can get the data you want using `fopen` and `fread`, then you're good. Note, you probably don't need to invert the matrix to take the average you want, since you can just change from looking for all values in a row, to all values in a column, etc.

Comment: The inversion is actually for a step later on in the process before I can contour plot it. It's not actually something that I necessarily needed to mention. But indeed, I can successfully use the fopen and fread commands successfully. I guess the question is, how do I loop it through and take that average? Can those subsequent steps you posted earlier still work?